# Symfony 2 : Handle COM Object

Tags: com, symfony

I would like to use a COM object in my Symfony 2 Controller. COM must be a part of PHP 5, so I guessed there would have been no problem.

Here is my code:

```
$ObjectFactory = new COM("CrystalReports11.ObjectFactory.1");
```

And Symfony returns me this error:

```
Class 'App\InterfaceBundle\Controller\COM' not found
```

I'm on Windows 7, using PHP 5.3. When displaying phpinfo, I can see COM object support enabled.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any PHP inclusion to make in the Controller to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're working in a namespace called `App\InterfaceBundle\Controller`, so PHP is looking for the class `COM` within that namespace.

Changing your code to the following will explicitly tell PHP to load the class from the "global space" rather than the current namespace:

```
$ObjectFactory = new \COM("CrystalReports11.ObjectFactory.1");
```

You can read more about namespaces in the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php